# Running my python code in Gitbash

Tags: python

I am a total newbie in programming so I was hoping anyone could help me. I am trying to write program in python that, given an integer n, returns me the corresponding term in the sylvester sequence. My code is the following:

```
    x= input("Enter the dimension: ")
    def sylvester_term(n):
    """ Returns the maximum number of we will consider in a wps of dimension n

    >>> sylvester_term(2)
    7
    >>> sylvester_term(3)
    43
    """
    if n == 0:
        return 2

    return sylvester_term(n-1)*(sylvester_term(n-1)-1)+1
```

Now, my questions are the following, when trying to run this in GitBash, I am asked to input the n but then the answer is not showing up, do you know what I could do to receive the answer back? I plan to continue the code a bit more, for calculating some other data I need, however, I am not sure if it is possible for me to, after coding a certain piece, to test the code and if so, how could I do it?

Comment: Are you taking in command line arguments. If so, can you show us the entirety of the program?

Comment: I don't think I am taking command line arguments and at the moment this is all I have of the code.

Comment: If this is the entire code, than you are not even handling input, therefore nothing is supposed to happen.

Comment: I added a first line and now the program, when ran in GitBash asks me for an n, but then again it is not printing anything. I tried adding something like print(x) but it is giving me an error of the form print(sylvester_term(x)) but I am getting an error.

Comment: Make sure you cast x to int. What is the error?

Comment: That was the problem thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add:

```
print(sylvester_term((int(x)))
```

to the end of your program to print the answer.

You will need to cast to int because the Python Input() function stores a string in the variable. So if you input `5` it will return `"5"`

This does not handle exceptions, e.g if the user inputs a letter, so you should put it in a try and except statement.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem ! I will consider the exceptions! One question, doesn't python read the number as an integer when I input it in the Bash?

Comment: @urpi No, Python reads all input (when using the input() function) as a string. Updated the answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I'd handle it. You can use `sys.argv` to get the arguments passed via the command line. The first argument is always the path to the python interpreter, so you're interested in the second argument, you can get it like so:

```
sys.argv[1]
```

Once that is done, you can simply invoke your function like so

```
print(sylvester_term(int(sys.argv[1]))
```